# Why my code not working for python list rotate

Tags: python, list

My Code. I have wrote the code for rotating the list

```
s = 'abc'
lst = list(s)
for x in range(0,len(lst)):
    lst =  lst[-x:] + lst[:-x]
    print (lst)
```

My Out

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Expected Out

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['b', 'c', 'a']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're overwritting you're original list and hence in the second iteration you're rotating and additional position and ending up with the same list. Create a temporary variable:

```
s = 'abc'
lst = list(s)
for x in range(0,len(lst)):
    lst_ =  lst[-x:] + lst[:-x]
    print (lst_)

['a', 'b', 'c']
['c', 'a', 'b']
['b', 'c', 'a']
```

---

Just as a side note - you might find `collections.deque` interesting for such task:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(s)
for _ in range(len(s)):
    print(d)
    d.rotate()

deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])
deque(['c', 'a', 'b'])
deque(['b', 'c', 'a'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the answer of @yatu, you can rotate your list by only one element in each loop iteration:

```
s = 'abc'
lst = list(s)
print(lst)
for x in range(0,len(lst)-1):
    lst =  lst[-1:] + lst[:-1]
    print (lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `deque` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

```
from collections import deque
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bar = deque(foo)
for _ in range(len(bar)):
    print(bar) # or ptint(list(bar))
    bar.rotate()
```

You can rotate in both directions and at arbitrary steps.